# Extract predictions from all modles that are part of the pipeline using R mlr3

Tags: r, mlr3

Below, I have created mlr3 graph and trained it on sample dataset.

I know how to create predictions for final ste (regression average), but is it possible to get predictions for models before averaging? The goal is to compare individual model performance with final model.

Bonus question, can individual models be autotuners themselves and if yes, how to incorporate them in pipeline?

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3tuning)

# task
mlr_tasks
task = tsk("mtcars")

# graph
learners_l = list(
  ranger = lrn("regr.ranger", id = "ranger"),
  xgboost = lrn("regr.xgboost", id = "xgboost")
)
choices = c("ranger", "lm", "kknn", "xgboost")
learners = gunion(learners_l) %>>%
  po("regravg", innum = length(learners_l))

# create graph
graph = gunion(list(
    ranger = lrn("regr.ranger", id = "ranger"),
    xgboost = lrn("regr.xgboost", id = "xgboost")
  )) %>>%
  po("regravg", innum = length(learners_l))
plot(graph)
graph_learner = as_learner(graph)

# search space
search_space = ps(
  ranger.ranger.max.depth = p_fct(levels = c(2L, 3L))
 )

# auto tuner
at = auto_tuner(
  tuner = tnr("grid_search"),
  learner = graph_learner,
  resampling = rsmp("holdout"),
  measure = msr("regr.mse"),
  search_space = search_space,
  term_evals = 2,
  store_models = TRUE
)

# train
at$train(task)

# IS IT POSSIBLE TO EXTRACT PREDICTIONS OF RANGER AND XGBOOST TO COMPARE IT WITH ENSAMBLE?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trained learners are located in the `$graph_model` slot.

```r
at$model$learner$graph_model$pipeops$ranger.ranger$predict(list(task))

at$model$learner$graph_model$pipeops$xgboost.xgboost$predict(list(task))
```

> Bonus question, can individual models be autotuners themselves and if yes, how to incorporate them in pipeline?

Yes. `AutoTuner` objects are learners and can be used like learners. You have to decide whether this makes sense.

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but haven\t tried the code :) If I use above code it will give prediction for ranger for the task. But not the predictions for the preprocesed task. I would like to get predictions that classif avedecidesrae uses when it decide on final predictions. From the above code, it seems it will just do lm on initial task.

Comment: 1) There are no preprocessing steps in your pipeline 2) You said "I know how to create predictions". So I assumed that you train your pipeline (`at$train(task)`) and then call `at$predict(your_prediction_data)`. To get only the predictons of each trained learner, you would call `at$model$learner$graph_model$pipeops$ranger.ranger$predict(list(your_prediction_data))`.